# Openproject community 13 All-in-one container - migrate from docker to new docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, openproject

I have executed the following command to setup an open project community 13 from the docker for a month.

```
docker run -it -p 8080:80 -e OPENPROJECT_SECRET_KEY_BASE=secret -e OPENPROJECT_HOST__NAME=localhost:8080 -e OPENPROJECT_HTTPS=false -e OPENPROJECT_DEFAULT__LANGUAGE=en openproject/community:13
```

Then I would like to migrate the environment to the new docker under the new machine.

I have tried the following step from the new machine.

Step 1.
( save from old machine )

```
docker save -o openproject.tar
```

The tar file can be saved from old machine.

```
docker load -i openproject.tar
```

The image can be restored on the new machine.

Step 2.

```
docker run -it -p 8080:80 -e OPENPROJECT_SECRET_KEY_BASE=secret -e OPENPROJECT_HOST__NAME=localhost:8080 -e OPENPROJECT_HTTPS=false -e OPENPROJECT_DEFAULT__LANGUAGE=en openproject/community:13
```

The new open project community 13 with docker container is built from new machine and can be browsed, but old data cannot be restored.

I have tried to export the backup sql from the ( old docker environment ) open project - administration by web.

The owner of openproject db under debian - postgresql is unknown.

Is there any idea about the migration / restore ?

Comment: `docker save` saves an image to file - you need to save a running container. If you don't mount any volumes to the container you might be able to use `docker export` instead - or maybe both (save/load for the image and export/import for the container). Personally though I'd mount volumes for application data to the container and just copy those.

Comment: You should note that your setup is not the recommended production setup... as the first paragraph in this section makes clear: https://www.openproject.org/docs/installation-and-operations/installation/docker/#using-this-container-in-production

Comment: I have tried to export / import ( docker run ) to migrate at the beginning. After I have complete the import and start the contain, the web application cannot be browsed and the service under debian has not been started.

Comment: How can I rebuild the docker with corrected step ?

Comment: I cannot say why it doesn't work - you'll have to inspect the container logs and content